# xslt: Add element/attribute in different node by reading value form other

Tags: xslt, wix, heat

I have below xml document

**XML**

```
<Wix>
  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
        <Component Id="JA" Name="MY_XYZ">
            <File/>
        </Component>
        <Component Id="ZH" Name="MY_ABC">
            <File/>
        </Component>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="COMPREF">
        <ComponentRef />
        <ComponentRef />
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Here i want to read value of component's attribute Name and use that value to set ComponentRef's attribute. so the componentref should look like this

**Desired Output**

```
<ComponentRef SomeAttr="MY_XYZ"/>
<ComponentRef SomeAttr="MY_ABC"/>
```

How to achieve this using XSLT?

Comment: How is the relation between a `ComponentRef` and a `Component` established, simply by position (i.e. first `Component` provides name for first `ComponentRef`?

Comment: @MartinHonnen i didn't get your point but yes each component have its corresponding component reference so i want to create `ComponentGroup` in a separate `Fragment` where i can add `ComponentRef` for each `Component`. I have also edited question to make it clear for what i exactly want. Please help i did lot google but couldn't find.

Comment: @MartinHonnen after trying both the template its giving some strange result. it might be because of i am reading from different node level. Could you please look at [this](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18LSwr5UYmqcLa8AdJX7R1FQIJ2CXKGla?usp=sharing) actual files and let me know the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your other needs you can either strip-space and apply-templates to use `position()` to use the index of the `ComponentRef` child element of `ComponentGroup` to find the `Component` child with the same index:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ComponentRef">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
        <ComponentRef SomeAttr="{/Wix/Fragment/DirectoryRef/Component[$pos]/@Name}"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

or you need to write the second template as

```
    <xsl:template match="ComponentRef">
        <xsl:variable name="pos"><xsl:number/></xsl:variable>
        <ComponentRef SomeAttr="{/Wix/Fragment/DirectoryRef/Component[position() = $pos]/@Name}"/>
    </xsl:template>
```